# manage decimal values in output summary

Tags: r

sample data:

```
dataa<-data.frame(
  aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
col2=c(2,1,1,7,4,1,2,7,5,7,2,6,2,2,6,3,4,3,2,5,7,5,6,4,4,6,5,6,4,1,7,3,2,7,7,2,3,7,2,4)
)
```

sum<- expss::cro_cpct(dat2[[1]],dat2[[2]])

Comment: Instead of `round` use `sprintf` eg: use `sprintf("%0.1f%%",22)`

Comment: tried this      .fns = ~ sprintf("%0.1f%%",22)
but whole summary transformed as 22.0%

Comment: haha, you should understand that what i posted was an example. I said to use `sprintf` instead of `round`. of course you do not have `round(22)` anywhere in your code but rather has `~round(.x, digits = 1)` so you should have `~sprintf("%0.1f%%", .x)`

Comment: He He , yes i am little new in R, i have used this also but still not working
can explain me how it can help me exactly in my code

Comment: You desire to have a number with one decimal place. `sprintf` is the function to use to determine the number of decimal places that you want.  So what exactly do you mean by it is not working? Please read on how to use `sprintf`

Comment: To get an answer that you want, I allow you to ask a question although you will have to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that contains your problem. Once the problem in the example is solved, you can be able to use that to solve your issue

Comment: i have just updated reproducible example , and also updated required output

Comment: How do you call `tab_std_cross` function?

Comment: crosstab_sum(dat1 = dataa,var1 = "col1",var2 = "col2")

Comment: There is no `crosstab_sum` function. Also the arguments in `tab_std_cross` are not `var1` and `var2`

Comment: my bad , i had changed the name of function
tab_std_cross (dat1 = dataa,var1 = "col1",grouping_var="col2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function :

```
library(expss)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

tab_std_cross <- function(dat1,var1,grouping_var){
  
  var1 <- parse_expr(var1)
  var2 <- parse_expr(grouping_var)
  
  dat2 <- dat1 %>% select(!!var1,!!var2)
  var_lab(dat2[[1]]) <- ""
  var_lab(dat2[[2]]) <- ""
  tab1 <- cro_cpct(dat2[[1]],dat2[[2]]) 
  tab1 <- as.data.frame(tab1)
  tab1[which(tab1[,1]=="#Total cases"),1] <- "N"
  tab1[is.na(tab1)] <- 0
  tab1 <- tab1 %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        .cols = where(is.numeric),
        .fns = ~ round(.x, digits = 1)
      )
    )
  tab1[tab1 == 0] <- '--' # --- (1)
  mask_indices <- sapply(tab1, function(x) x[length(x)] %in% c(3, 4, 5)) %>%
    which()  
  tab1[, mask_indices] <- "--"
  tab1[-nrow(tab1), -c(1, mask_indices)] <- sapply(
      tab1[-nrow(tab1),-c(1, mask_indices)], function(x) # --- (2)
    ifelse(x != '--', paste(format(as.numeric(x), nsmall = 1), "%"), x)) # --- (3)
  tab1 <- flextable(tab1)
  tab1
}
```

Things changed in the function :

1. Replace all 0 values with `"--"`
2. Removed column 1 from turning into `"%"` since it does not make sense to add `"%"` sign to row labels.
3. Used `ifelse` to avoid turning `"--"` to `"-- %"`.
   Showed numbers only till 1 decimal place.

```
tab_std_cross (dat1 = dataa,var1 = "col1",grouping_var="col2")
```

[image]

Comment: one more thing , all values should visible in decimal points. like 50% in last column should reflect as 50.0%
actually all values which is followed by .0 should reflect as .0 but its reflecting as round values with decimal =0

Comment: where to use this options(digits = 3) in my code...???
with paste(format(as.numeric(x), nsmall = 1) ...??